# How to use 2D matrix rows as indices and function arguments?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I'm writing code for loop-less geometric image transformation with bi-linear interpolation using meshgrids. What i'm trying to achieve is something like this in the final step :

```
image(column1 of A , column2 of A)=func (rows of nx3 matrix B as arg);
```

suppose A = [1 2 ; 3 4 ; 5 6] and B=[1 1 1 ; 2 3 1 ; 4 5 1] so that this should happen :

```
image (1,2)=func ([1 1 1]);
image (3,4)=func ([2 3 1]);
image (5,6)=func ([4 5 1]);
```

without using any loop. Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you not change the function ? like `image = func(A,B)`?

Comment: You should restructure your code such that `func` accepts `image`, `A` and the entirety of `B`, and outputs the modified image. If you insist on calling `func` on every row separately, I don't see how it can be done w/o an implicit (i.e. `arrayfun`) or an explicit loop. Regardless, you should provide a [mcve] - please include an example `image` (both input and output). I suspect your `func` can be vectorized, but your question is too abstract to really tell.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is vectorized, simply:

```
image(sub2ind(SizeofImage,A))=func(B);
```